# Flutter & Firestore: Are there any steps that can cause errors when using the batch?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Are there any steps that can cause errors when using the batch? I want to set all the batch that I want to use. Then I will commit these together.

For example:

```
Future batchSet() async {
  // step 1
  WriteBatch batch1 = FirebaseFirestore.instance.batch();
  WriteBatch batch2 = FirebaseFirestore.instance.batch();

  // step 2
  for (var value in data1With100Docs) {
    batch1.set(FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('batch1').doc(), {
      'createAt': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      'data': value,
    });
  }
  for (var value in data2With400Docs) {
    batch2.set(FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('batch2').doc(), {
      'createAt': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      'data': value,
    });
  }
  for (var value in data3With400Docs) {
    batch2.set(FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('batch2').doc(), {
      'createAt': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      'data': value,
    });
  }

  // step 3
  await batch1.commit();
  await batch2.commit();
}
```

Which step can make an error? (1,2,3) Or if you have the step more than me you can suggest these to me. If my steps are wrong or not correct you can suggest me too. I am new to firebase.

If steps 1 or 2 can make an error, I will check try/catch over these to commit or not.

If step 3 is the only step that can make an error, I will manage this with my method and my code doesn't want to use try/catch over steps 1 and 2.

I don't know how to make this error to test this.

Comment: The main question is... "are you getting any?"

Comment: I don't understand. Should I change the title of this question?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this code:

```
Future batchSet() async {
  try {
    // step 1
    WriteBatch batch1 = FirebaseFirestore.instance.batch();
    WriteBatch batch2 = FirebaseFirestore.instance.batch();
    print("Step 1");

    // step 2
    for (var value in data1With100Docs) {
      batch1.set(FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('batch1').doc(), {
        'createAt': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
        'data': value,
      });
    }
    for (var value in data2With400Docs) {
      batch2.set(FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('batch2').doc(), {
        'createAt': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
        'data': value,
      });
    }
    for (var value in data3With400Docs) {
      batch2.set(FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('batch2').doc(), {
        'createAt': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
        'data': value,
      });
    }
    print("Step 2");

    // step 3
    await batch1.commit();
    await batch2.commit();
    print("Step 3");
  } catch (e) {
    print("Error -> $e");
  }
}
```

I don't know how to make steps 1 and 3 errors. So, I close the internet. The program show `Step 1` and `Step 2` in the console and then shows `[2022-10-13T17:32:38.367Z]  @firebase/firestore:` with a loop.

```
Step 1
Step 2
[2022-10-13T17:32:38.367Z]  @firebase/firestore:
[2022-10-13T17:32:38.368Z]  @firebase/firestore:
[2022-10-13T17:32:38.372Z]  @firebase/firestore:
[2022-10-13T17:32:38.373Z]  @firebase/firestore:
[2022-10-13T17:32:39.021Z]  @firebase/firestore:
[2022-10-13T17:32:39.461Z]  @firebase/firestore:
[2022-10-13T17:32:40.888Z]  @firebase/firestore:
[2022-10-13T17:32:40.943Z]  @firebase/firestore:
[2022-10-13T17:32:43.108Z]  @firebase/firestore:
[2022-10-13T17:32:44.234Z]  @firebase/firestore:
[2022-10-13T17:32:46.996Z]  @firebase/firestore:
```

I guess this loop is the `await batch.commit();`. The firebase tries to commit this. After some minutes, I open the internet, and the console show `Step 3`.

When I change the firebase rule with this collection can't write. the result in the console is:

```
Step 1
Step 2
Error -> [cloud_firestore/permission-denied] Missing or insufficient permissions.
```

In another situation. I change the map data to an empty map or anything that isn't a map.
The console will show:

```
Step 1
Error -> Expected a value of type 'Map<String, dynamic>', but got one of type 'LinkedMap<dynamic, dynamic>'
```

So I think step 1 can't error, step 2 can error with invalid input type, the step 3 can error with permission denied by firebase rules or another reason from the firebase.